# Unary Operator-() on zero values - c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, unary-operator

I wrote this code to overload the unary operator- on a matrix class:

```
const RegMatrix RegMatrix::operator-()const{
    RegMatrix result(numRow,numCol);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<numRow;++i)
        for(j=0;j<numCol;++j){
            result.setElement(i,j,(-_matrix[i][j]));
        }

        return result;
}
```

When i ran my program with debugger in visual studio, it showed me that when the operation is done on a double equals zero, it inserts the result matrix the number -0.00000.
Is it some weird VS-display feature, or is it something i should handle carefully?

Comment: This should help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: They still compare equal don't they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Signed zero is zero with an associated
>   sign. In ordinary arithmetic, −0 = +0
>   = 0. However, in computing, some number representations allow for the
>   existence of two zeros, often denoted
>   by −0 (negative zero) and +0 (positive
>   zero). This occurs in some signed
>   number representations for integers,
>   and in most floating point number
>   representations. The number 0 is
>   usually encoded as +0, however it can
>   be represented by either +0 or −0.
>
> The IEEE 754 standard for floating
>   point arithmetic (presently used by
>   most computers and programming
>   languages that support floating point
>   numbers) requires both +0 and −0. The
>   zeroes can be considered as a variant
>   of the extended real number line such
>   that 1/−0 = −∞ and 1/+0 = +∞, division
>   by zero is only undefined for ±0/±0.
>
> Negatively signed zero echoes the
>   mathematical analysis concept of
>   approaching 0 from below as a
>   one-sided limit, which may be denoted
>   by x → 0−, x → 0−, or x → ↑0. The
>   notation "−0" may be used informally
>   to denote a small negative number that
>   has been rounded to zero. The concept
>   of negative zero also has some
>   theoretical applications in
>   statistical mechanics and other
>   disciplines.
>
> It is claimed that the inclusion of
>   signed zero in IEEE 754 makes it much
>   easier to achieve numerical accuracy
>   in some critical problems,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) in
>   particular when computing with complex
>   elementary functions.[2] On the other
>   hand, the concept of signed zero runs
>   contrary to the general assumption
>   made in most mathematical fields (and
>   in most mathematics courses) that
>   negative zero is the same thing as
>   zero. Representations that allow
>   negative zero can be a source of
>   errors in programs, as software
>   developers do not realize (or may
>   forget) that, while the two zero
>   representations behave as equal under
>   numeric comparisons, they are
>   different bit patterns and yield
>   different results in some operations.

For more information see [Signed Zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) wiki page.

Answer (score 2):

using double ([IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point_standard)), there is defined positive and negative zero.

Answer (score 0):

Well for doubles actually have different values for '0.0' and '-0.0' I think it makes perfect sense....

What different result did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

As ereOn said, you've got a negative zero:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", -0.0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

-0 and 0 are the same thing, and it is nothing to worry about. Floating point numbers have the capability to have both a positive and negative 0, for math reasons. But -0 is interpreted the same way as 0 in C/C++ arithmetic.

Comment: I don't think thats special for C/C++, but for the FPU used (or IEEE754 emulation library used)