# C++ ceil and negative zero

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, floating-point, ceil

On VC++ 2008, `ceil(-0.5)` is returning `-0.0`. Is this usual/expected behavior? What is the best practice to avoid printing a `-0.0` to i/o streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ceil` in C++ comes from the C standard library.

The C standard says that if a platform implements IEEE-754 arithmetic, `ceil( )` behaves as though its argument were rounded to integral according to the IEEE-754 **roundTowardPositive** rounding attribute.  The IEEE-754 standard says (clause 6.3):

> the sign of the result of conversions,
>   the quantize operation, the
>   roundToIntegral operations, and the
>   roundToIntegralExact is the sign of
>   the first or only operand.

So the sign of the result should always match the sign of the input.  For inputs in the range `(-1,0)`, this means that the result should be `-0.0`.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct behavior.  See [Unary Operator-() on zero values - c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881937/unary-operator-on-zero-values-c) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

I am partial to doing a `static_cast<int>(ceil(-0.5));` but I don't claim that is "best practice".

Edit: You could of course cast to whatever integral type was appropriate (uint64_t, long, etc.)

Comment: I'm outputing as `double`, not casting.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod If you must use `double`, you must accept that negative zero is valid.  If you don't want it to print the negative sign, you could add checking code like the following `std::cout << (ceil(x) == -0.0) ? 0.0 : ceil(x);`.  Are you using double because you want the ".0"?

Comment: Right, it's a fixed width floating point output. I still don't see why `ceil` should ever return `-0.0`.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: `ceil` can return -0.0 because it returns `double` (or `float` or `long double`) and -0.0 is valid for all those types.  If you look at your standard library's implementation of `ceil()` you'll likely discover that it uses `modf()`, which in turn uses `fmod()` to get the fractional part of the argument to `ceil()` and subtracts it from the argument to `ceil()`.  In your case, this means it does `-0.5 + 0.5`.  If you simply do `std::cout << (-0.5 + 0.5);`, what do you get?

Comment: @Chris: that would be a *truly* bizarre implementation of `ceil( )`.

Comment: @Stephen, you're right, it's too late to do basic math apparently ;) I'm just going to post the link instead: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#aJtAZx52vVs/trunk/lib/math/ceil.c&q=ceil&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc

Comment: @Chris, I get `-0.5 + +0.5 == +0.0`. But see my answer.

Comment: @Chris: It's worth noting that the implementation you linked to actually *doesn't* conform to IEEE-754 (in the default rounding mode, it will return `+0.0` for `ceil(-0.5)`, whereas IEEE-754 says the result shall be `-0.0`).

Answer (score 1):

I can't say that I know that it is usual, but as for avoiding printing it, implement a check, something like this:

```
if(var == -0.0)
{
    var = 0.0;
}
// continue
```

Comment: apparently operator `==` does not distinguish between `-0.0` and `+0.0`, (not that is matters in this case).

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: That's because -0.0 == +0.0 according to IEEE754.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Comparisons

Comment: this code snippet is just to act as a buffer, to make sure that you are not printing the negative sign.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is usual.

```
int number = (int) ceil(-0.5);
```

number will be 0

Answer (score 0):

I see why `ceil(-0.5)` is returning `-0.0`. It's because for negative numbers, `ceil` is returning the integer part of the operand:

```
double af8IntPart;
double af8FracPart = modf(-0.5, & af8IntPart);
cout << af8IntPart;
```

The output here is "-0.0"

Comment: That's what I was alluding to in my (arithmetically incorrect) comment in my original answer.  Thanks for posting the example.